# Is there any simple way to use timer in our android application?For Example I want to start or schedule a task after some time(Ex :30 mins)

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi is there any simple way to use timer in our application to stop our activity.

Comment: See `CountDownTimer` - http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: First, tell us what exactly do you want to achieve. Then, we'll know what kind of solution do you need.

Comment: User should enter particular time after which he will informed about the progress of the activity.So I want to know how to use timer...and how a user can enter time after which he could know progress.

Comment: For Example I want to start or schedule a task after 30 mins or 1hr or 2hr..The application should know when to start. So Is there any simple way for this or should I go with Alarmmanager along with time picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/) is an example of how to do it using a Handler:

The code is like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */
      foobar();
      /* and here comes the "trick" */
      handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
   }
};
```

The easiest way but not very recommended by Google is using the java Timer class.
As I have seen it, java.util.Timer is the most used for implementing a timer.
Just create a method that will be called when the time is over.

For a repeating task:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
```

For a single run of a task:

```
new Timer().schedule(task, after);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi I like ur answer but I want user input to be taken as argument in place of interval. For Example I want to start or schedule a task after 30 mins. Thanks for ur reply :)

Comment: In the interval, parse to int or long the String you get from the EditText where the user types the interval

Comment: Thanks Isaac it helped.